# Can I access c# HttpContext.Current.Session with angular?

Tags: c#, angular

I've got some issues with an API rest project. In order to use the API controllers I have to login, which I did successfully, but when I change the page or refresh I lose the connection. In the web API I've implemented session with HttpContext.Current.Session but I cannot access this session with angular. Is it possible at all?

My auth controller:

```
using Echo.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Echo.Controllers
{
    public class AuthController : ApiController
    {
        private EchoContext db = new EchoContext();

        // OPTIONS: api/auth
        public IHttpActionResult OptionsAuth()
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetAuth()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] != null)
            {
                var u = (User)(HttpContext.Current.Session["user"]);

                return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {u.Id,u.Name,u.Mail} );
            }
            else
            {
                var e = new CustomResponse();
                e.HttpCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                e.Message = "No user logged in";
                return Content(e.HttpCode, e);
            }
        }

        public IHttpActionResult DeleteAuth()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] = null;
                var e = new CustomResponse();
                e.HttpCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                e.Message = "Disconnected successfully";
                return Content(e.HttpCode, e);
            }
            else
            {
                var e = new CustomResponse();
                e.HttpCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                e.Message = "No user logged in";
                return Content(e.HttpCode, e);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult PostAuth(Auth auth)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] != null)
            {
                var e = new CustomResponse();
                e.HttpCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                e.Message = "You are already connected";
                return Content(e.HttpCode, e);
            }

            try
                {
                    User u = db.Users.Where(x => x.Name == auth.Name).First();
                    if (u.Password == auth.Password)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] = u;
                        return Ok(new { u.Id, u.Name, u.Mail, u.CreationTime });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var e = new CustomResponse();
                        e.HttpCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                        e.Message = "wrong credentials";
                        return Content(e.HttpCode, e);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    var e = new CustomResponse();
                    e.HttpCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                    e.Message = "Unknown user";
                    return Content(e.HttpCode, e);
                }

        }
    }
}
```

The API work fine with PostMan, once i'm logged in i can access others controller.

My component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ConnexionService } from '../../services/connexion.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-connexion',
  templateUrl: './connexion.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./connexion.component.css']
})
export class ConnexionComponent implements OnInit {

  auth = new FormGroup({

    Name : new FormControl(''),
    Password : new FormControl('')
  });

  donner: string;
  connectedUser: string;

  constructor(private service: ConnexionService, private router: Router, private cookie: CookieService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.connectedUser = localStorage.getItem('user');

  }

  getAuth() {
    const donner = {
      'Name': this.auth.controls.Name.value,
      'Password': this.auth.controls.Password.value
    };

    this.Authentification(donner);
  }


  Authentification(donnerFormulaire: any) {

    this.service.envoieConnexion(donnerFormulaire).subscribe(
      (data: any) => { /*this.router.navigate(['/ModifierUtilisateur']);*/
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log(data); },
      error => { console.log(error); }
    );
  }

}
```

My service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Form, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})



export class ConnexionService {

  private  loggedInStatus = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('loggedin') || 'false');

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


   httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
  };

  setLoggedIn(value: any) {
  }

  get isLoggedIn() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedin') || this.loggedInStatus.toString());
  }

  envoieConnexion(donneeFormulaire: any): any {

    const body = JSON.stringify(donneeFormulaire);
    return this.http.post('https://echorestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Auth/', body, this.httpOptions);
  }

  getConnexion(user: any) {
    this.http.get('https://echorestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Auth/', user);
  }
}
```

Comment: you'll have to ajax that to the client somehow